# Rails + Heroku: A foreign key constraint fails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, heroku

I am trying to seed my MySQL database for my Rails project on my Heroku server and I am getting this error:

> ActiveRecord::InvalidForeignKey: Mysql2::Error: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`heroku_b08bb4ad8dfb726`.`posts`, CONSTRAINT `fk_rails_5b5ddfd518` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`)): INSERT INTO `posts` (`id`, `title`, `description`, `user_id`, `category_id`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES (1, 'Title', 'Desc', 1, 1, '2016-08-29 06:53:04', '2016-08-29 06:53:04')

Surprisingly, I do not get this error in my **development** environment.

The extract of my **Seed file** looks like this:

```ruby
# Creating Users here

Category.create!([
  { id: 1, name: "Category"},
])

Post.create!([
 { id: 1, title: "Title", description: "Desc", user_id: "1", category_id: "1" },
])
```

**Post model:**

```ruby
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :category
  has_many :comments
  validates :title, :description, presence: true
end
```

**Category model:**

```ruby
class Category < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :posts
end
```

Please let me know if you need any more code snippets in the comments. Thank you very much for any ideas on this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also need to create user in your **seed.rb**

Constraint is failing because you don't have `user` in your database with `id = 1`

Add this in your seed file

```
user = User.create(
  # user attributes like `name`
)

Post.create!([
 { id: 1, title: "Title", description: "Desc", user_id: user.id, category_id: "1" },
])
```

Also I will suggest instead of hardcoding the values like `user_id` you should use `first` or `last` or random record to avoid constraint failure

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Sorry, I am already creating the users before in the seed file. Have edited my question.

Comment: Then make sure the `user_id` you are passing the user is present

Comment: Now I am facing this problem here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39200815/mysql-rails-errno-150-foreign-key-constraint-is-incorrectly-formed